# Use Seasonal ARIMA model parameters in Matlab

Tags: matlab, forecasting, arima

I have the hourly electricity demand of a household for a year. I determined the ARIMA order by using auto.arima in R and now I want to use the received ARIMA order to estimate and forecast the next 24 hours in a MATLAB program.

Lets assume the fitted model is of order: p = 2, d = 0, q = 2; P = 2, D = 1, Q = 0 (frequency = 24). So an arima (2,0,2)(2,1,0)[24] model. How do I insert these parameters into the arima function in Matlab? So far i got:

```
%Create arima model
Mdl = arima(p,d,q);
Mdl.Seasonality = frequency;

%Estimate the coefficients
EstMdl = estimate(Mdl,past_data);

%Run the forecast for the next 24 hours
[yF,yMSE] = forecast(EstMdl,24,'Y0',past_data);
```

But that does not include the seasonal parameters so far. Indeed, I am quite confused by the documentation provided by mathworks.

Thankful for any suggestions!

Max

Comment: This question seems to be more about general theory on Arima models rather than programming. Might be more suited for stats.

Comment: @Oliver thanks for that suggestion. I might better ask the first part in stackexchange. I try to edit the question to focus on the part of the matlab coding.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience in matlab, but looking at the [documentation for arima](https://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/arima.html;jsessionid=959e2305974b5d49254fbf9b1270) it might be possible to specify the model as

```matlab
c = 0;
p = 2;
d = 0;
q = 2;
S = 24;
P = 2;
D = 1;
Q = 0;
arima('constant', c, ...
      'ARLags', p, ...
      'D', d, ...
      'MALags', q, ...
      'Seasonality', D * S, ...
      'SARLags', D * P * S) %, ...
%      'SMALags', D * Q * S) %commented seasonal MA because D * Q * S = 0
```

This is based on the **Create SARIMA Model Template** example from the link above, and seems to execute properly in their online IDE. Note due to my lack of any experience in matlab, i have not checked the results comparing model estimates. Note as well that `'Seasonality'`, `'SARLags'` and `'SMALags'` must be positive integers (or lacking), Otherwise an error seems to be returned.

Comment: thanks for your answer! May I ask why you multiply the SARLags and the SMALags with the Seasonality? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems to be a nieche of the Matlab arima function. But logically it is not that hard to understand. A seasonal ar or ma is similar to a regular ar or ma, except performed over the seasons rather than single periods. This if we wanted a sar2 model, this simply translates to an ar model with 2 coefficients for the first two seasonal periods. (possibly oversimplified. Its been a while since I had to work on the theory of time series.)